# How to describe n-way ANOVA in text?

Tags: anova, reporting

When describing an n-way ANOVA in text, is it best practice to specify the number of factors *and* the number of levels in each factor? Here are some examples with varying amounts of information:

- "We ran a two-way ANOVA."
- "We ran a two-way ANOVA (factors A and B)."
- "We ran a two-way ANOVA (factors A, 3 levels, and B, 8 levels)."

This is probably field-dependent, but I'm wondering if there's a convention out there.

Comment: I think it is field dependent as you suggest -- the conventions vary from field to field and even journal to journal (to the extent that there are any at all).  I know that as a reader, I'd definitely want to know the third thing (and a good deal more besides) rather than the first. I'd prefer to err on the side of more information - concisely presented - where you can (better to have to take some out than add more in; the larger version might be called a working paper and made available to people that seek more details).

Comment: One possibility is: We ran an A(3) x B(8) ANOVA.